# Submit same form twice with different inputs

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sorry for the 'repeated' question. I have checked other questions on this topic but can't get to solve my problem. Hope you can help me.

You see, I need to submit a form with some particular input (not all of them), I'm doing this using AJAX and Jquery like this

```
$('#msform').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  $.ajax({
    url  : action,
    type : 'POST',
    data : $('#form1, #msform :input:not(.exclude)').serialize(),
    success : function() {

    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

It's working fine. It only sends the serialized inputs I want it to send `( $('#form1, #msform :input:not(.exclude)').serialize() )` and all. 
But, AFTER THAT, I need it to be send again with some different input when the user clicks a button.
Here's my code for that:

```
$('#acepto').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var action2 = $('#msform').attr('action');


    $.ajax({
        url  : action2,
        type : 'POST',
        data : $('#msform :input.formu2').serialize(),
        success : function() {
            var data = $('#msform :input.formu2').serialize();
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Now that code makes nothing, it doesn't send my form again as I want it to and I haven't been able to find my mistake. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Your `#acepto` click handler is assigning a submit event handler for `#msform`, but it's not actually submitting anything. Is that intentional, or are you expecting this submit to happen when you click `#acepto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is that clicking the `#acepto` button submits the form, then your confusion is that you're assigning a submit handler to the form instead of actually doing the submit. The submit handler originally assigned will cause the form to be submitted when you click a submit button. The accept button doesn't need to change the submit handler; it can just do the submit directly:

```js
$('#acepto').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var action2 = $('#msform').attr('action');
  $.ajax({
    url: action2,
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#msform :input.formu2').serialize(),
    success: function() {
      var data = $('#msform :input.formu2').serialize();
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Well, I used to have my code just like yours but it still didn't submit anything. My situation in here is that I have my submit event being handled by an external Php File (given by the company I work with, but, still, my first submittion worked with the data i wanted it to work ( $('#form1, #msform :input:not(.exclude)').serialize() ) ), so I tried this code (exactly like yours) in order to perform the second submition, but it didnt work. 
I'll then assume the problem is not in my code but in the Php given to me by this company.

Comment: I ended up with the mess I show in here when trying to make it work. Thanks for correcting it. Now I think that this mistake is just not my fault but the Php-file's fault.

Comment: Do you see the submit taking place in your developer tools network tab? If by "doesn't work" you mean no submit request is happening, then it's still on your end. If you see a submit happening but it's not doing what you expect after that, then maybe is the fault of the PHP.

Comment: I do see the Submit (status:200, Method:Post) taking place in my Network tab both times. They (the people I work with) tell me it's submitting just once, tho (the first time).

So I'll assume it's the file's fault. Thanks for taking your time to answer my question.